# transform before animation in Mozilla

Tags: css, animation, transform, scale, mozilla

I have some images in a banner that I am want to transform (scale) however I want to do this before the animation is performed, as I don't want the scale to be animated. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<span class="animate"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg/1024px-Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" /></span>

#banner img{
zoom:0.66;
-moz-transform: scale(0.66);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(0.66);
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.66);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform: scale(0.66); /* Standard Property */
transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 50px;
}

#banner span{
-webkit-animation-duration: .6s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
-moz-animation-duration: .6s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-ms-animation-duration: .6s;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
-ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-duration: .6s;
animation-timing-function: ease;
animation-fill-mode: both;

-webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
-moz-animation-delay: .2s;
-ms-animation-delay: .2s;
animation-delay: .2s;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more code context? It's a little tough to solve with the small snippet you've given

Comment: The banner has a series of images, some animate from the left, some the right. The site is now being moved to bootstrap as we need it responsive. Only smaller devices the images are too large, so I need to reduce their width and height. This is working in Chrome, but Moz is a no go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to set when animation **A** ends it will start animation **B**.

A solution to your problem I believe can be found [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end)